# TimePickerDialog theme change

Tags: android, time, themes, timepicker

I wrote this code to make a [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) box

```
btnDialBoxTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        MyTimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new MyTimePickerDialog(AdvancedCDT.this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault, timeSetListener, 0, 0, true);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set hours and minutes"); 
        timePickerDialog.show();

    }

    });
```

The dialog box appear correctly but the Theme is white.

I would like to have it black/gray which is the default of my Nexus 7.

The android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault does not seem to function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one of the five built-in `AlertDialog` themes:

- [`THEME_TRADITIONAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_TRADITIONAL) - The traditional (pre-Holo) alert dialog theme
- [`THEME_HOLO_DARK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_HOLO_DARK) - The holographic alert theme with a dark background
- [`THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_HOLO_LIGHT) - The holographic alert theme with a light background
- [`THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK) - The device's default alert theme with a dark background.
- [`THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT) - The device's default alert theme with a light background.

**For instance**:

```
    MyTimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new MyTimePickerDialog(AdvancedCDT.this,
            TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, timeSetListener, 0, 0, true);
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry, my bad, your answer and one small other addition solved it !
Thanks